# How to install sonarqube developer edition via Docker?

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I’m trying to install Sonarqube Developer Edition server but after installation, in footer page, it shows that it’s the Community Edition that is installed.
Here is my docker command:

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube --restart=always -p 9000:9000 -e sonar.jdbc.url=<my_jdbc_url> -e sonar.jdbc.username=<my_db_user> -e sonar.jdbc.password=<my_db_password> --network sonarqube_network --volume sonarqube:/opt/sonarqube sonarqube:9.7.1-developer
```

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

`docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube:developer`

Navigate to http://localhost:9000

Or you may be able pass your variables directly in by running:

`docker run -d -e SONAR_TOKEN=<YOUR_TOKEN> -e SONAR_EDITION=developer -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube:developer`

Comment: Hi, both not work and gives me the following error: 
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for sonarqube:developer-edition not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Comment: Try again but using the sonarcube:developer image

Comment: Already tried that, otherwise I solve my problem with docker compose

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something in my script, but otherwise I managed to solve my problem with docker compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:9.7.1-developer
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: <my_jdbc_url>
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: <my_db_username>
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: <my_db_password>
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
```